# Angular 7: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined when building my production code

Tags: angular, build, typeerror

I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined in angular when I am trying to build production code.
I  tried to update angular devkit version but no luck.
I don't want to update angular version and also not want to set build optimizer false.
I attached the screenshot of dev dependency.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core"; 
@Input() planNumber:string;
```

```html
<plan-status [planNumber]="planNumber"></plan-status>
```

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "angular8app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.7.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "docx": "^5.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^7.3.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

````
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular8app/fesm5/angular8app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16370:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16265:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16322:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16333:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\a675259\Downloads\Angular7Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16229:21) ```
````

Comment: It'd be easier to check if you post the code snippet where the error occurs. Also cannot find the screenshot you mentioned.

Comment: Now I have added package,json and error

Comment: try to search something like "?.kind" or ".kind" in your project. Somethere type or default value is incorrect. In html & ts files u can replace "***.kind" to "***?.kind" that must help u (but need check from what ng version u can use "?.")

Comment: @НикитаСереда I am not using kind  property in my project. I am getting this error when I am running this command ng build --prod

Comment: Did you upgrade some Angular-Dependencies recently? The error points to a problem with `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. From my experience I can tell that this mostly happens when your other Angular-Dependencies are incompatible with the dev-kit-builder's version. You have to juggle a litte by going some iteratiations up or down. I'd say you have to go some versions up.

Comment: @Lynx242 Yes I have tried different version of third party library but no luck and also tried to upgrade the angular devkit version

Comment: Angular 7 was released in 2019, your version of the dev-kit-builder last year. There is a gap of 1 year. Do you use a versioning system like GIT or Subversion? Can you check if this gap always existed or came with your third party lib?

Comment: @Lynx242 I have tried different @angular-devkit/build-angular from 0.10.7 to 0.13.8 but same issue I am getting

Comment: @Lynx242 When I am using Input(angular/core) in my component library then I am getting this issue and when I removed Input from npm library then it's building successfully.

Comment: Can you please show this code snippet? I would like to see how you apply `@Input()`.

Comment: @Lynx242 Yes I have added that

Comment: Well, the syntax seems okay, although I'd prefer if you'd add the type definition  like `@Input() planNumber: number;` or so. Because then you exactly know what type `planNumber` is supposed to have. Anyway, can you please provide the code where you use planNumber? I need to see both, HTML and TS.

Comment: @Lynx242 Yes I added the both HTML and TS. I am passing planNumber as a string

Comment: Well, I can't tell what the problem might be. All I can say is, that it is obviously not caused by your code, which is absolutely correct. Sorry.